# Ошибка необработанного исключения

Tags: c, dll

Пишу код на языке СИ:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int a = 0;

    printf("Введите a: ");
    scanf("%d", a);
    printf("%d", a);

    getchar();
}
```

И при запуске получаю ошибку:

> Необработанное исключение в "0x5d9ae42e (msvcr100d.dll)" в "helloworld.exe": 0xC0000005: Нарушение прав доступа при записи "0x00000000".

Помогите!

Comment: `scanf("%d", a);` -> `scanf("%d", &a);`

Comment: Включите предупреждения в настройках компилятора.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я не уверен, что в VS есть такая диагностика.

Comment: @Qwertiy https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xjsvsoW4s

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, не у всех самая последняя версия студии. Вот так компилируется этот код в VS2010: https://i.stack.imgur.com/crWeQ.png. Или даже так, если отключить ругание на использование подобных функций: https://i.stack.imgur.com/96Dn4.png.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну, это уже винтаж. :)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> scanf("%d", a);
> ```

```
scanf("%d", &a);
```

<s>Кстати, присваивание нуля совершенно лишнее.</s>

Comment: Если `scanf` не сможет считать число (букву ввели, например), то переменная `a` не будет инициализирована => `printf` попытается получить значение неинициализированной переменной => UB => присваивание нуля устраняет неопределённое поведение.

Comment: @wololo, согласен, не подумал про такой вариант.